# Javascript xsltProcessor transformToFragment asynchronously (Firefox), how to control when it is done?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, firefox, xslt-1.0

I am transforming a large XML document with the XSLT engine of Firefox. When this file is too large for Firefox, the browser just freezes (much earlier in Mac Os - i7 than in a Windows - core 2 duo, surprising).

As a way to make easier the process, I have split the XML file in small parts, transforming them serially. This has improved things (and velocity) a lot. However, when the file is still large, I have the same symptoms.

Now, what I think is happening is that the `transformToFragment` function is asynchronous. It means that I am starting the following transformation before the previous one has finished, and at the end it blocks the browser (and actually the computer as well).

Then, I cannot find any event that I could rely on before continuing with the process. Does anybody have any idea of how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

At the end, it doesn't seem asynchronous. I have tried to control it checking the value of the response every x seconds, but I didn't check anything until the transformToFragment process ended.

I still have problems in avoiding that this process freezes the browser and the computer. Now I would wish this process was asynchronous. In any case, this is not related to this "wrong" question.